# asynchronous call returns failure handler all the time

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got 2 scripts.

bounded - where I create custom menu and calling HTML form 
standalone - where is that HTML form I need to call

in standalone script that I use as library I need asynchronous call for function in bounded script to get some data from sheet.

**standalone script**

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).withFailureHandler(onFailure).runMyBoundedScript();
```

**bounded script**

```
function runMyBoundedScript(){
  return 'this is my value to return';
}
```

problem is that it always return me failure handler no matter what. If I delete this function from bounded script it returns nothing. When I add it's always failure. Do not understand why. Any help please!!!

Comment: What error is it returning ? Did you tried logging that in onFailure function ?

Comment: Both scripts needs to be in the same project. Make both bound or both unbound.

Comment: Umair Mohammad - it doesn't return actually any error the function will pass but with failure option.

Comment: TheMaster - I can not create a project...I'm using g-suit and I'm not allowed to do so in my company :/

Comment: You already have a project. The *standalone* script needs to be bound- in the same project as the bound one. Side note: Notify users with `@` like @Umair

Comment: @TheMaster: yes if the project means to create a script and save it by some name I do have project. Now I had a look on google how to assign standalone script to project but I found nothing. Any help please?

Comment: Is your html really a [standalone script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone)?

Comment: Could you provide [mcve] with all logs/alerts? What do you mean by *When I add it's always failure*? Do you have a function named `onFailure`  and do you get `this is my value to return` inside there?

Comment: @TheMaster: yes I'm sure it's standalone script. I can see it in projects overview it's not bounded to any google dosc. I can not give you any error logs as it's not throwing   any exceptions. The script and function will run. But with failure action and it not triggers any alerts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DONE!

I just wrote same function for both script.

Bounded and Standalone script must have `runMyBoundedScript()`

I thought I can call standalone function within bounded script thanks to the library like

```
runMyBoundedScript(){libA.runMyStandaloneFunction()}
```

but it seems it doesn't work that way. Now it's working and I'm actually getting success option in return.

Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: Please whenever you can mark your answer as correct. See: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/